# c# exception not caught

Tags: c#, exception

I have a method that is a listener for a TCP client which looks like this:

```
    private static void ProcessClient(
        Object obj)
    {
        ISession session = (ISession)obj;
        NetworkStream networkStream = null;

        try
        {
            DebugUtility.SetThreadName("Worker: {0}", session.Name);
            networkStream = session.TcpClient.GetStream();
            networkStream.ReadTimeout = Config.ReadTimeout;

            // Loop received packets (blocks untill next packet)
            Int32 packetSize;
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[session.PacketSize];
            while ((packetSize = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                // Get String from packet  bytes
                String packet = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, packetSize);

                // Check if packet has data
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(packet))
                    continue;

                // Log biggest received package
                DebugUtility.CheckMaxPacketSize(session.Name, packet.Length);

                // Handle packet (in new thread)
                Logger.DebugLog("Received: {0}", packet);
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(session.HandlePacket, packet);
            }
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException) { }
        catch (NotSupportedException) { }
        catch (TimeoutException) { }
        catch (SocketException) { }
        catch (IOException) { }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogException(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (networkStream != null)
                networkStream.Close();

            if (session != null)
                session.Disconnect();
        }
    }
```

This is for a game service but when I check my logs, I occasionally see this error:

```
System.Int32 Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32): The stream does not support reading.
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at BusinessLayer.Listener.ListenerWorker.ProcessClient(Object obj) in C:\path\ListenerWorker.cs:line 141 Line: 0
```

That is the above described file and line 141 is

```
        while ((packetSize = networkStream.Read(buffer,....
```

Now I have found that NotSupportedException is throwing this error, but why does it go through? Why is it not ignored but does it fall through the normal Exception ex handler?

Edit: Does anyone know how I can invoke this exception? When does it occur? I only see it coming back in my logs to other users, but I don't know when it happens.

Comment: First thing I would fix in this code is to stop swallowing a big chunk of your exceptions. Since you have a logger system, why are you actively swallowing the most relevant exceptions without any trace at all?

Comment: Can't agree more!  Why on earth are you doing this to all your lovely exceptions - they're there to help you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`NetworkStream.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) is throwing an `InvalidOperationException`, not a `NotSupportedException` (contrary to the documentation). You can confirm this from Reflector:

```
if (!this.CanRead)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("net_writeonlystream"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never ever **ever** swallow an exception unless you are 100% sure that you can do something about it and recover from it. Swallowing all exceptions implies that **whatever happens**  your program can recover and continue. What if it's an OutOfMemoryException or a StackOverflowException, can you program handle those gracefully? Yes log the exception, but for the love of god, rethrow it and let it do its job :)